# Как в питоне вернуть из потока значение?

Tags: python, многопоточность, рекурсия

```
import sys
import threading

def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * f(n - 1)

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
threading.stack_size(0x2000000)

t = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(2023,))
t1 = threading.Thread(target=f, args=(2020,))

t.start()
t1.start()

# здесь необходимо вернуть значение из потока и посчитать f(2023) / f(2020)
```

Возможно ли это? Если да, то как это реализовать?

Comment: 1)Для вычисления факториала рекурсия не нужна 2)Оба факториала можно посчитать за один раз 3)Более того, и факториалы считать не нужно, т.к. ответ `2023*2022*2021`

Comment: @MBo просто интересно, можно ли реализовать именно так)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()

def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * f(n - 1)

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

feature1 = pool.submit(f, 2023) # создаем поток для вычисления факториала
feature2 = pool.submit(f, 2020)

result1 = feature1.result() # забираем результат вычисления
result2 = feature2.result()

result = result1/result2
print(result)
```

Comment: Этот код завершает работу с ошибкой 0xC00000FD

Comment: @TastePate проверьте сейчас, я именем переменной ошибся.

Comment: Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

Comment: @TastePate у меня выводит `8266912626.0`. Попробуйте вернуть строку `threading.stack_size(0x2000000)`

Comment: оно не работает потоками, сначала отрабатывает первое, и ждет окончание первого, и только потом выполняет второе